# MS Dynamics CRM - Send Out of office emails only on selected dates for the incoming emails from CRM

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, workflow, microsoft-dynamics

I have the scenario where the out of office emails needs to be triggered for the incoming emails on some particular days (say January 1, December 25, October 2) of the year. We have those days as a holiday list.

If all the incoming emails which comes on January 1st, then for all the emails the out of office email should be sent back to the email sender from the corresponding CRM mail box.
Need your valid suggestions!!!

Answer (score 0):

My suggested solution would be:

1. Have one custom field in Email activity 'OOF to be sent?'
2. Setup a Pre-operation plugin on Create of Email (Check only for Incoming Email in ExecutionContext) & set the above custom field to 'YES' in target entity itself based on your Holidays config verification
3. Another asynchronous Post create Plugin on Email can send out OOF email based on this custom field value (You can have an UI workflow to send Email using template, this Post create plugin can simply execute this WF to send out OOF email)